# How can i override a save action in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm just a newbie in Odoo.I want to override the save method in creating customer in the sales tab(i'm using odoo 8).
SO when i click save i will send an XML RPC message to some other system(ESB).
I will do this kind of overriding in many odoo modules(including ad dons) but i don't know from where i start?
I have right now installed odoo on my system as well as downloading the source code from the git repository (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0) 
Any idea please how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override Create function in Odoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749586/override-create-function-in-odoo)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, because we're talking about customers here and the button is "save". Yes, the solution will be partially the same, but same solutions don't make questions duplicates :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually two ORM methods could be called. On creation the save button will call the models `create()` and on update/write it will call `write()`. So you have to create you own custom module and override these methods. You should call the `super()` and then do what ever you want to do with your external system.
There are a lot of examples in Odoo itself where such overrides are done, already.

Comment: should i create a new module or just override the create method in the accounting asset module or just recompile the full odoo source code?

Comment: this functionality i found it in the addons folder(called accounting asset)?

Comment: I would never recommend to override the odoo code. Always write your own custom modules. Try to look into an Odoo development tutorial, for example [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html). The Odoo model you have to inherit and override its methods is `res.partner`.

Comment: OK that looks fine but now i'm at the study of fesability. So as per your understanding that thing is fesable(overriding the save of creating assets in odoo)??

Comment: How did you come from overriding customer save (your question) to accounting assets?

Comment: actually i have both tasks to do but i will start by this override creating asset in odoo

Comment: In the end you need to find the odoo models you want to override and do always the same in your custom module for them.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example :

```
from openerp import models, api

class ResUsers(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.users"

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        self.do_something_else()
        return super(ResUsers, self).create(vals)

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        res = super(ResUsers, self).write(vals)
        self.do_something_writefully_different()
        return res
```